# Get the call duration outgoing call : android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to get the last outgoing call duration of an outgoing call.

Here is the short code.

```
     Uri contacts = CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI;     
     Cursor managedCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
                                contacts, null, null, null, null);
     int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
      if (managedCursor.moveToLast()) {
                String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
          }
```

Where callDuration gives the total call duration in seconds.
It works fine with Build version sdk lesser than 21 (LOLLIPOP). But in lollipop based version phones reporting wrong call duration.which is not the exact duration of the call for the outgoing call.

Ex: If call start time is 12:00:00 and call end time 12:00:30(Total Call duration = Ringing duration + answered duration)
and actual call duration of the call is 20 seconds(answered duration) but lollipop based phones are showing total call duration i.e 30 seconds which is misleading when the user is trying to do an outgoing call and the call is not answered/connected still duration shows (CallEndTime-CallStartTime) in seconds.

Reported the same in android open issue tracker. Still no solution/turnaround found.

Comment: Got any answer for this yet?

Comment: @Marwadi It's the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79592) in lollipop. Yet to fix.